# ng-switch-when with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

My HTML code is

```
<tr ng-switch-when="true" ng-repeat="onlineCredentials in onlineCredentialDetails" >
        <td>
            <span>Ordering Mode: </span>{{onlineCredentials.mode}}<br />
            <span>Intermedtiary Group: </span>{{onlineCredentials.name}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>Website: </span>{{onlineCredentials.webSite}}
        </td>
        <td >
            <span>Username / Password</span>
            <div ng-repeat="cred in onlineCredentials.loginDetails">
                -&nbsp;{{cred.userName}}&nbsp;/&nbsp;{{cred.password}}
            </div><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Which is not binding data... (TD s and text is present but binding property values are empty)

How to work with ng-switch-when and ng-repeat at a time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15434085/1264360. Basically to fix you need to have the ng-switch-when in an element above the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 28):

ng-switch requires a parent to have a

```
ng-switch on="variableName"
```

and children to have

```
ng-switch-when="stuff1"
```

Example with ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="value in values" ng-switch on="value.color">
    <div ng-switch-when='blue'>Blue</div>
    <div ng-switch-when='green'>Green</div>
    <div ng-switch-when='orange'>Orange</div>
</div>
```

and your collection for ng-repeat might look like:

```
$scope.values = {
    one: {color: 'blue', worth: 2},
    two: {color: 'green', worth: 3},
    three: {color: 'orange', worth: 4},        
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/YavzpaPUBaBQNA0pHMPN?p=preview