# AngularJS ng-repeat: Passing the current binding element to a function for Conditional Rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know we can achieve conditional binding with `ng-repeat` through the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="viewer in allViewers track by viewer.Id">
   <td>
      <img width="18" ng-src="{{!viewer.StatusByUser || viewer.StatusByUser != 1 ? 
         '/images/icons/hide.svg' : '/images/icons/show-18x11.png'}}" 
         onerror="this.src='/images/icons/hide.svg'" alt="Viewer Status" 
         title="Click to {{!viewer.StatusByUser || viewer.StatusByUser != 1 ? 
         'publish' : 'unpublish'}}" ng-click="manageViewerStatus(viewer.StatusByUser)">
   </td>
</tr>
```

But as you can see, this is messy and in reality, I have at least **5 to 6 status to keep track of** and change the display image icon accordingly.

In JavaScript, we know that there is a way to pass the current element to a function:

```
<img src="/images/icon.jpg" onclick="changeAttr(this)" />
```

But in Angular, I tried the following but not working:

**In HTML:**

```
<img data-bind="{{renderStatusImg(this, viewer)}}" width="18" alt="Viewer Status"
   title="Click to publish" ng-click="manageViewerStatus(viewer.StatusByUser)">
```

**In controller:**

```
$scope.renderStatusImg = function (img, viewer) {
   $(img).attr("src", !viewer.StatusByUser || viewer.StatusByUser != 1 ? '/images/icons/hide.svg' : '/images/icons/show-18x11.png');
   // More complex logic can be written here in future to cater for more status.
   return viewer.Id;
};
```

As a result, `viewer.Id` can be returned and rendered in `data-bind` attribute, but the `src` attribute isn't rendered. I have heard of the **directive approach** but seems like it can only deal with the indexes of the underlying data and not the element itself. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by **@Ruben Helsloot**, the question itself may not be a good practice. Apparently, not all technical questions have their own direct good answer, but all **goals** may have variety of solutions to achieve them for the same result, of which they may include best practices, moderate solutions, or even just a work-around. Therefore, it's good for solution seekers to share also **their GOALS** as their question alone may not be a recommended good practice.

## Now my answer: Using [`ng-switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495052/ng-switch-when-with-ng-repeat/23495783#23495783) for the same goal

After a more extensive research, I found `ng-switch` is my perfect solution: Cleaner, less code, more extensible and readable, yet more Angular native:

```
<tr ng-repeat="viewer in allViewers track by viewer.Id" ng-switch on="viewer.StatusByUser">
   <td>
      <img ng-switch-when="0" src="/images/icons/hide.svg" width="18" alt="Draft" title="Click to publish" ng-click="manageViewerStatus(viewer)">
      <img ng-switch-when="1" src="/images/icons/show-18x11.png" width="18" alt="Published" title="Click to unpublish" ng-click="manageViewerStatus(viewer)">
      <img ng-switch-default src="/images/icons/hide.svg" width="18" alt="Old version" title="Click to fix" ng-click="manageViewerStatus(viewer)">
   </td>
   <td>
      <!-- More other columns that bound by viewer.StatusByUser can be benefited 
           from this approach. -->
   </td>
</tr>
```

Take note of the `ng-switch-default`, it is one of the main factors that led me to choose `ng-switch`: It can handle `null` and `undefined` object property, great for allowing you to offer fallback and upgrade services to your users. Notice also the `title` and `alt` attributes, I can properly define them in every conditional tag for `ng-switch` -- No complex code and logic required. Note that I don't even have to write a single additional JavaScript to handle this. Thanks to `ng-switch`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using such a function to get the correct `src` value, but not write it back to it - that's actually bad practice. Instead, consider a list or an object, where the key is related to the iterator, and the value is the `src` of the image:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="viewer in allViewers track by viewer.Id">
   <td>
      <img width="18" ng-src="viewerImages[viewer.Id]" alt="Viewer Status" 
         title="Click to {{!viewer.StatusByUser || viewer.StatusByUser != 1 ? 
         'publish' : 'unpublish'}}" ng-click="manageViewerStatus(viewer.StatusByUser)">
   </td>
</tr>
```

```js
$scope.viewerImages = {};
$scope.allViewers.forEach((v) => {
  $scope.viewerImages[v.Id] = getViewerImage(v);
});

function getViewerImage(viewer) {
   // More complex logic can be written here in future to cater for more status.
   return !viewer.StatusByUser || viewer.StatusByUser != 1 ? '/images/icons/hide.svg' : '/images/icons/show-18x11.png';
};
```

Comment: Which means for every iteration of the binding, I need to iterate through `allViewers` again just to populate the image src? Can I populate the `viewerImages` first before assigning `allViewers` to the `$scope`? Would that be better?

Comment: What do you mean by "every iteration"? Whenever the data changes? Because that true, but that happened in your example as well, and even more often with the `ng-if`. But, if the data changes for only some, you don't have to calculate all of them, which is a benefit. Of course you can populate `viewerImages` first, it doesn't matter. AngularJS only fires a `$digest` cycle when the code is idle, so if you assign them in the same function, order is not a problem.

Comment: I mean when every `<tr>` is bound, will your code loop through the whole `allViewers` data source again? Which means if I have 20 viewers, will it loop through **20x** just to determine the `src` for each `img`? I was thinking about using the `Map` API to simplify the code and logic, because not only the `src`, many other attributes will need to be changed according to the `StatusByUser`, e.g. `title` and `alt`.

Comment: No, I meant to do it in the controller, either as you fetch the data or as you initialise the controller. That means do it once.